# How to split a string with certain delimiters in java

Tags: java

I have a string as

```
[Ian Wood P. M. Visscher]
[Ian Wood L. Mengersen]
[Ian Wood]
[P. M. Visscher Ian Wood].
```

I want to write this string into two dimensional array. (i.e)String

```
a[0][0]=Ian Wood ,
a[0][1]=P. M. Visscher,
a[1][0]=Ian Wood,
a[1][1]=L. Mengersen and so on.
```

Every time when I would give input, the names in the string will change.How do I split it and store it in the above form in the array. Please suggest any idea . Thanks in advance.Following is the code I worked on,but does not split properly.

```
String[] parts = output.split(" ");
String[][] table = new String[parts.length / 2][2];
for (int i = 0, r = 0; r < table.length; r++) {
table[r][0] = parts[i++];
table[r][1] = parts[i++];
}
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString(table));
```

Comment: Why can't you delimit your names with some other delimiter? like `#` or anything that will not be in the name?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean initials as "certain delimiters", and your input string is an array of strings:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE;
import static java.util.regex.Pattern.compile;

public final class Q14914678 {

    private static final Pattern pattern = compile("^\\s*((?:[a-z]+\\s*?)*)\\s*([a-z]\\..*)?", CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    private static final String[] names = {
            "Ian Wood P. M. Visscher",
            "Ian Wood L. Mengersen",
            "Ian Wood",
            "P. M. Visscher Ian Wood"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<String[]> collected = new ArrayList<String[]>();
        for ( final String name : names ) {
            final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
            if ( matcher.matches() ) {
                collected.add(new String[] {matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2)});
            }
        }
        for ( final String[] array : pairArray ) {
            out.println(array[0] + " / " + array[1]);
        }
    }

}
```

The result is as follows:

```
Ian Wood / P. M. Visscher
Ian Wood / L. Mengersen
Ian Wood / null
 / P. M. Visscher Ian Wood
```